# error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown' when try pipe slice in *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I trying to use NGB Pagination on my angular app in a table. But when i use pipe slice in my *ngFor, my Angular appear error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown' when try slice. This is my code:

1. My HTML code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of documentaryList|slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize" class="text-md text-md-center">
                  <td>{{ row.documentDate }}</td>
                  <td><a class="text-info" routerLink="details-documentary/{{row._id}}">{{ row.documentName }}</a></td>
                  <td>{{ row.documentNumber }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row.documentType }}</td>
                  <td>{{ row.documentAddress }}</td>
                  <td>
```

2. My .ts code:

```
export class ListDocumentaryComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Documentary';
  documentaryList: any;
  page = 1;
  pageSize = 10;
  lengthDocumentList = 0;

  constructor(private documentaryService: DocumentaryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDocumentaryList();
  }

  getDocumentaryList(): any {
    this.documentaryService.getDocumentary()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.documentaryList = data.data;
        this.lengthDocumentList = this.documentaryList.length;
      });
  }

}
```

3. My Object in console:
   [image]
4. And my Error:
   [image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if you try `this.documentaryList = data.data as any;`

Comment: if `documentaryList` is an array, Declare it as array `documentaryList:any[]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `documentaryList: any;` to  `documentaryList: any[] = [];`

> In TypeScript, the choice of types can significantly impact the
> quality and reliability of your code. While the any type provides
> flexibility by allowing a property to hold values of any type, it also
> forfeits TypeScript's core benefit: type checking. Using any
> essentially tells TypeScript to disable type-checking and assume
> minimal restrictions, which can lead to potential issues with type
> safety and reduced code clarity. By opting for a more specific type,
> such as an object, you introduce more structure to your code. This
> allows TypeScript to perform type-checking and provide meaningful
> IntelliSense suggestions, catching type-related errors at compile-time
> rather than runtime.

Comment: In my case data is declared as object. 
i.e - data: any = {listData: []}; //.ts
*ngFor="let d of data.listData | slice:0:sliceCount; let i = index;" //.html
& trying to use <div [class.active-row]="d.id === i">inside loop</div>
// !! it showing <Object is of type 'unknown'>

Answer (score 1):

Another way :

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of obj.list.slice((page-1) * pageSize, page * pageSize)" class="text-md text-md-center">
   <td>{{ item.prop1 }}</td>
   <td>{{ item.prop2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

This works when the looped list is a property of an object (type **any**)

Comment: this one actually worked for me, thanks. not a big fan to changing something to any or any[], seems like a hack, this way I was able to keep my strongly typed array