# Angular NgFor Path Issue

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my Angular Application I have a simple `ngFor` loop showing logo images like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list" class="logo-wrapper">
    <div class="customer-logo">
        <span
            class="my-icon"
            aria-label="My icon"
            [inlineSVG]="'./assets/image/projects/logo/' + item.logo">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is working fine!
But: If I try to slice the Array to limit the output as follow:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list | slice: 0:10; let i = index" class="logo-wrapper">
    <div class="customer-logo">
        <span
            class="my-icon"
            aria-label="My icon"
            [inlineSVG]="'./assets/image/projects/logo/' + item.logo">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get this Error : "**Object is of type 'unknown'**".

Error output:
[image: Error Output]

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Edit: The problem appears as soon as I add a index to the loop.
I tried to add the index to the object like: ***item.i.logo*** but its also unknown.

PS: Here is my .ts-file

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-logo-section',
    templateUrl: './logo-section.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./logo-section.component.scss']
})
export class LogoSectionComponent implements OnInit {
    list : any

    constructor() 
    {
        this.list = getProjects()
        console.log(this.list)
    }

    ngOnInit(): void 
    {
    }

    private services = [{
        slug : "s-l-u-g",
        name : "name",
        work : "work",
        company : "company",
        website : "https://www.google.com",
        preview : "text",
        logo : "logo.svg"
    }]

    getProjects()
    {
        return services
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the ts code?

Comment: @deepakchethan ts file is added

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68532422/error-ts2571-object-is-of-type-unknown-when-try-pipe-slice-in-ngfor) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change the type of `list` to `any[]` instead of `any`. Update the declaration as follows in your typescript file.

```
list : any[];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `SlicePipe` deprecates with the `ng-inline-svg` package because it uses `HttpClientModule` and works `asynchronously`.

if you use `Array.slice` method instead of the `SlicePipe` in the `*ngFor` it works fine.

Please find the [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-akwvkj?file=src/app/app.component.html).

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list.slice(0, 10); let i = index" class="logo-wrapper">
  <div class="customer-logo">
    <span class="my-icon" aria-label="My icon" [inlineSVG]="item.logo"> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```